# How do I append Google Test's XML output to an existing XML file?

Tags: xml, unit-testing, jenkins, junit, googletest

So Google Test allows you to write output to an XML for logging purposes and possibly for consumption by a Continuous Integration service. I want to take advantage of this facility. Apart from the regular key/value pairs the default XML output provides, the `RecordProperty("key", value)` function allows a person to append addition user-defined info to the XML output. For example, one property would be (`execution_time=0.56ms`).

What I want to do is to get a **time-series** of these keys/values, that I can later plot using a plugin in a CI to visualize the execution time taken by various tests after various changes. Essentially, I want Google Test to to append to the same XML file after running each test (each test is determined by its unique timestamp / commit ID / custom parameter). Does Google Test allow you to do this?

If Google Test does **not** allow to append to an existing XML file, I am thinking of using RapidXML and replicate the same structure of a Google Test report (conforming to the JUnit format). However, can a JUnit-conformant XML document consist of more than 1 `<testsuites>`? Since each `<testsuites>` is a complete test run, can I have multiple `<testsuites>` in the same XML document and still conform to JUnit (so that Jenkins consumes it easily?)